# Grafana cloud datasource - How to get datasource URL

Tags: grafana, jaeger

I'm trying to set up a Jaeger datasource in grafana cloud.
In Jaeger datasource page - URL field is empty, my question is: Where can I find the required URL? I have tried to write an imaginary URL, for test purpose, and when I clicked on 'Save & Test' I've got no error feedback, but when I tried to pick Jaeger datasource in explore page I've got 'Failed to load services from Jaeger. Failed to fetch'.

So I'm confused, can someone help me understand which URL should I use and where can I find it?
(I'm using grafana cloud)

Answer (score 1):

The URL should be the "Jaeger Query" endpoint, you need to find it from the Jaeger service instance in your K8s for example.